# Issue with Imagenet classification with VGG16 pretrained weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I was trying to run a vanilla Image net classification with VGG16 network in tensorflow (which gives out VGG16 through Keras backbone).

However when I tried to run classification on a sample elephant image it is giving completely unexpected results.

I am not able to figure out what might be the issue.

Here is the complete code I used:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.applications import imagenet_utils


model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16()
VGG = model.graph

VGG.get_operations()
input = VGG.get_tensor_by_name("input_1:0")
output = VGG.get_tensor_by_name("predictions/Softmax:0")
print(input)
print(output)

I = Image.open("Elephant.jpg")
new_img = I.resize((224,224))
image_array = np.array(new_img)[:, :, 0:3]
image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)


with tf.Session(graph=VGG) as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    pred = (sess.run(output,{input:image_array}))
    print(imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(pred))
```

The below is the sample output I get:

> Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
>   Tensor("predictions/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
>
> [[('n02281406', 'sulphur_butterfly', 0.0022673723), ('n01882714', 'koala', 0.0021256246), ('n04325704', 'stole', 0.0020583202), ('n01496331', 'electric_ray', 0.0020416214), ('n01797886', 'ruffed_grouse', 0.0020229272)]]

From the probablities it loooks like there is something wrong with the passed Image data (as all are very low).

But I couldn't figure out what is wrong.
And I am very sure the image is of an elephant as a human!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we can (or need to?) use the session from Keras (which has the associated loaded graph with weights) instead of creating a new session in Tensorflow and using the graph obtained from Keras model like below

```
VGG = model.graph
```

I think the graph got above has no weights in it (and that is the reason predictions are wrong) and the graph from Keras session as the proper weights (so those two graph instances should be different)

Below is the full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K


model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16()
sess = K.get_session()
VGG = model.graph #Not needed and also doesnt have weights in it

VGG.get_operations()
input = VGG.get_tensor_by_name("input_1:0")
output = VGG.get_tensor_by_name("predictions/Softmax:0")
print(input)
print(output)

I = Image.open("Elephant.jpg")
new_img = I.resize((224,224))
image_array = np.array(new_img)[:, :, 0:3]
image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)
image_array = image_array.astype(np.float32)
image_array = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(image_array)

pred = (sess.run(output,{input:image_array}))
print(imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(pred))
```

And this gives the expected result:

> [[('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.8518132), ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.1398836), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.0082286), ('n01704323', 'triceratops', 6.965483e-05), ('n02397096', 'warthog', 1.8662439e-06)]]

Thanks [Idavid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429640/ldavid) for the tip about using preprocess_input() function and [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8044652/nicolas-m) for tips about unloaded weights.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 2 mistakes, the first one is that you must rescale your image by dividing by 255 all pixels.

```
I = Image.open("Elephant.jpg")
new_img = I.resize((224,224))
image_array = np.array(new_img)[:, :, 0:3]
image_array /= 255.
image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)
```

The second point I got it while looking at prediction values. You have a vector of 1000 element and all of them have 0.1% prediction after rescale. That means you have a non-trained model. I don't know exactly how to have if loaded in tensorflow but on Keras for example you can do :

```
app = applications.vgg16
model = app.VGG16(
        include_top=False,    # this is to have the classifier Standard from imagenet
        weights='imagenet',   # this load weight, else it's random weight
        pooling="avg")
```

From what I've read, you have to download another file containing weight from for example github.

I hope it helps,

**EDIT1:**

I tried the same model usign Keras :

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

I = Image.open("Elephant.jpg")
new_img = I.resize((224,224))
image_array = np.array(new_img)[:, :, 0:3]
image_array = image_array/255.
x = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=5)[0])
```

If I comment the rescaling, I have bad predictions :

> Predicted: [('n03788365', 'mosquito_net', 0.22725257), ('n15075141', 'toilet_tissue', 0.026636025), ('n04209239', 'shower_curtain', 0.019786758), ('n02804414', 'bassinet', 0.01353887), ('n03131574', 'crib', 0.01316699)]

Without the rescale, this is good :

> Predicted: [('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.95870858), ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.040065952), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.0012253703), ('n01704323', 'triceratops', 5.0949382e-08), ('n02454379', 'armadillo', 5.0408511e-10)]

Now if I remove the weight, I have the "same" as what I have with Tensorflow:

> Predicted: [('n07717410', 'acorn_squash', 0.0010033853), ('n02980441', 'castle', 0.0010028203), ('n02124075', 'Egyptian_cat', 0.0010028186), ('n04179913', 'sewing_machine', 0.0010027955), ('n02492660', 'howler_monkey', 0.0010027081)]

To me, that means that you have no weight applied. Maybe they are downloaded but not used.

Comment: thanks for your reply.For the point 1 you mentioned , I realized it later and with the modification the result is the same. About second point  VGG16() also provides the parameters you mentioned (weights and pooling) and their default values are just fine , so no problems here.And as you mentioned VGG16 downloads loads weights from github initially (From (DIRECT LINK TO FILE!!) https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5)

Comment: I replied by an Edit due to the size of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply , but still it didnt solve my problem.I checked in the sources of vgg16.py and there seems to be model.load_weights(weights_path) for all cases.

Comment: Yes, on keras you can load weight file (from a training already done for example) but I don't know the equivalent for Tensorflow. I didn't find something clear about that on Google but it's sure that there is something. I also checked on a book I have and he creates placeholder for weight and create himself the layer so this won't help too.

Comment: Don't divide by 255.0. Instead, use the `keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` utilitary. Also, comment `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer(), sess.run(init_op)`, which is reseting the weights to random values. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, if he switches to keras, he can refer to https://keras.io/applications/ . But I think he wants to do it only on tensorflow ? EDIT : I just tried it and I have an error message if I comment the 2 lines.

Comment: Yes , I want to do it in tensorflow and dont want t get into Keras APIs.Also if I comment those two lines as suggested by @Idavid , it gives error (Attempting to use uninitialized value block1_conv1/bias).Does that mean weights are not loaded?